# did Xcode 11 start ignoring missing 'return' statement errors?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

A coworker of mine can't compile the project (I think he's on an older version of Xcode, I'm on 11.2.1). But for some reason the code below has been working and compiling for me? I would think I should be getting syntax errors because of missing `return` statements?

```
    override func serviceType() -> ServiceType {
        .base
    }

    override func operationType() -> NQOType {
        .Post
    }

    override func doesSupportOffline() -> Bool {
        false
    }
```

Comment: `Functions With an Implicit Return; If the entire body of the function is a single expression, the function implicitly returns that expression.` from https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html But there have been changed between Swift versions if I remember correctly.

Comment: Add-on: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0255-omit-return.md Swift 5.1

Comment: It is because of Swift 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html

> Functions With an Implicit Return: If the entire body of the function
>   is a single expression, the function implicitly returns that
>   expression. For example, both functions below have the same behavior:

```
func greeting(for person: String) -> String {
    "Hello, " + person + "!"
}
```

> The entire definition of the greeting(for:) function is the greeting
>   message that it returns, which means it can use this shorter form.

Answer (score 0):

This works now as Swift 5.1 supports implicit return statements. If the body of a function is a single statement, the `return` keyword can be safely omitted as this statement is considered the return statement. This also applies for closures. More info can be found at the [Swift Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html)

Comment: "If a function has a single return statement, the return keyword can be safely omitted" is simply not true. If the entire body of the function is a single expression, the function implicitly returns that expression.

Comment: This is interesting because i'm actually compiling using swift 4, but using xcode 11.2.1, so maybe since XCode supports 5.1 it allows it and then just adds in the returns when actually compiling?